# Why is it allowed to have CountableRange with the same lowerBound and upperBound?

Tags: swift

```
let range = 3..<3 // lowerBound == upperBound
```

This type of range is used by the Swift Standard Library in multiple places, for example in the array `insert(_, at:)` method.

[Arrays.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4d7ae8ca855a840068a5512e099b5c2cad184b65/stdlib/public/core/Arrays.swift.gyb)

```
@_inlineable
public mutating func insert(_ newElement: Element, at i: Int) {
    _checkIndex(i)
    self.replaceSubrange(i..<i, with: CollectionOfOne(newElement))
}
```

When we write

```
let range = 5...5 // CountableClosedRange
range.lowerBound // returns 5
range.upperBound // returns 5
```

it means, we want a range that only cover one index that's `5`

But when we write

```
let range = 5..<5 // CountableRange
range.lowerBound // returns 5
range.upperBound // returns 5
```

How can we explain this?

**In short:** If range `5...5` represents index `5`, what does range `5..<5` represent?

Comment: What's weird about it? It's an empty range. When calling `replaceSubrange` with it, you're saying that you don't want any elements to be replaced; you merely want new ones inserted.

Comment: @Hamish If range `5...5` represents index `5`, what does range `5..<5`represent?

Comment: An empty range :)

Comment: Does it mean empty range is the way we tell the `replaceSubrange` to not replace anything, and just insert the new element at `lowerBound` (might also be `upperBound`) ? This what makes it weird. If we can use a single Index such as Int, why bother using empty range? :D

Comment: @Hamish this is not an empty range. Since the lower bound and upper bounds are equal (regardless of the ..< or ... operators) then the range will include only one number

Comment: @giorashc It doesn't include only one number; it doesn't include *any* numbers; `(5 ..< 5).count` is `0`, `(5 ..< 5).contains(5)` is `false`.

Comment: @hamish you are right.. the docs about this confused me.. joining the question then :)

Comment: `print((5..<5).isEmpty)` is `true`.  `(5..<5)` is *an empty range starting at position 5*.  The second part is key, because that makes it useful for `replaceSubrange` telling it where to insert.  Note that `(5..<5) != (6..<6)` even though both are empty.

Comment: @EdwardAnthony Exactly; and it's a nice way to encapsulate the entire implementation required to conform to `RangeReplaceableCollection` (a collection that supports resizing) in a single method (`replaceSubrange`).

Comment: As I explained in my answer, one of the most common places to see a CountableRange with lowerBound == upperBound is in `for` loops.  By using `..<` to form the range, it is possible to create an empty range and skip executing the loop entirely.

Comment: @vacawama now I see why it's allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **In short**: If range `5...5` represents index 5, what does range `5..<5` represent?

`5..<5` is *an empty range starting at position 5*.  You can verify that it is empty with:

```
print((5..<5).isEmpty)  // true
```

but note that:

```
(5..<5) != (6..<6)
```

because they start at different places.

As you noted in your question, an empty range can be useful for specifying a position.  In `replaceWithSubrange` it can be used to specify where to insert values.

Example:

```
var letters = ["a", "b", "c"]

letters.replaceSubrange(1..<1, with: ["x", "x", "x"])

print(letters)
```

> ```
> ["a", "x", "x", "x", "b", "c"]
> ```

This tells `replaceSubrange` to *replace the range of letters starting at position 1 for a count of 0 with `["x", "x", "x"]`*.  In other words, *insert the new values before position 1*.

---

Although you won't see range literals such as `(5..<5)` much in code, the empty range does occur often in code in `for` loops for example:

```
for i in 0 ..< array.count {
    // do something with i
}
```

In this case, if the array is empty, the range will have no values and the `for` loop will simply not execute.

Comment: Waow! seriously, I didn't mean to copy your answer :D

Comment: @AhmadF LOL.  If you did copy it, you did it in 23 seconds which is amazingly fast unless you're a bot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> **In short:** If range `5...5` represents index 5, what does range `5..<5`
>   represent?

Simply, empty range.

For:

```
let range = 5..<5
```

if you tried to check if it's empty, you should get `true`:

```
range.isEmpty //true
```

Consider:

```
let range = 5..<5
let testingArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let value = testingArray[range]
```

At this case, `value` would be an [ArraySlice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice) which contains *zero* elements.